# Firebase limit on the number of nodes/data returned in Snapshot

Tags: ios, firebase

When using Firebase iOS, is there a limit on the number of nodes/children/data returned when observing an event type `EventTypeValue` ?

```
[[self.firebase appendPathComponent:path] observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase will "return" all child nodes, unless you explicitly limit the number of nodes with `queryLimitedToFirst:` or `queryLimitedToLast:`. See the section of the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data) for some good examples of these.

One thing to constantly keep in mind when working with Firebase is that you're not just *querying* the data source, you're actively *synchronizing*, listening for changes as they happen. Say for example that you have a Firebase that contains status updates from you and your friends. And you have a page that shows the latest 10 updates.

1. Set up a query ordered by timestamp (a field in your status updates) with `queryOrderedByChild`.
2. Limit the query to latest 10 updates with `queryLimitedToLast:`.
3. You will receive 10 `FEventTypeChildAdded` events (assuming that there are at least that many status updates).
4. A friend posts a new status update.
5. Your page will receive a `FEventTypeChildRemoved` for the oldest status update and a `FEventTypeChildAdded` for the new status update.